# Android (java) XmlSerializer not encoding "Windows-1252"

Tags: java, android, encoding, xmlserializer

I'm currently working in a Android Studio project (java) and I need to export a Xml file with an specific encoding "Windows-1252".

I've been trying to do it for a few hours (EXAMPLE A) and no matter what kind of encoding I choose although the resulting file have the "correct" encoding in the first Xml line "... encoding='windows-1252'":

- the chars inside the Xml file are "escaped" with "&#xxx;"
- opening the file with notepad++ it detects the "UTF-8" encoding (not the desired "Windows-1252")
- `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252' ?><test><message>&#225;&#233;&#237;&#243;&#250;&#227;&#245;&#231;</message></test>`

To make sure that the "streams" were correct, I've created a new sample (EXAMPLE B) without the "XmlSerializer", and the result file was much better:

- the chars inside the Xml file are now correct (not escaped)
- opening the file with notepad++ it detects the "ANSI" encoding (not the desired "Windows-1252")
- `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252' ?><test><message>áéíóúãõç</message></test>`

```
private void doDebug01(){
        File dstPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        try {
            //EXAMPLE A
            File dstFile = new File(dstPath, "test.xml");
            FileOutputStream dstFOS = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
            OutputStream dstOS= new BufferedOutputStream(dstFOS);
            OutputStreamWriter dstOSW = new OutputStreamWriter(dstOS, "windows-1252");
            XmlSerializer dstXml = Xml.newSerializer();
            dstXml.setOutput(dstOSW);
            dstXml.startDocument("windows-1252", null);
            dstXml.startTag(null,"test");
            dstXml.startTag(null,"message");
            dstXml.text("áéíóúãõç");
            dstXml.endTag(null,"message");
            dstXml.endTag(null,"test");
            dstXml.endDocument();
            dstXml.flush();
            dstOSW.close();

            //EXAMPLE B
            File dstFileB = new File(dstPath, "testb.xml");
            FileOutputStream dstFOSB = new FileOutputStream(dstFileB);
            OutputStream dstOSB= new BufferedOutputStream(dstFOSB);
            OutputStreamWriter dstOSWB = new OutputStreamWriter(dstOSB, "windows-1252");
            dstOSWB.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252' ?>");
            dstOSWB.write("<test>");
            dstOSWB.write("<message>áéíóúãõç</message>");
            dstOSWB.write("</test>");
            dstOSWB.flush();
            dstOSWB.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

So now I'm confused and kind of stucked here with the results I've got from EXAMPLE B because I don't know if my problem (A) resides on the "XmlSerializer" or on the "streams" parameters.

What am I missing in my code (A) to get an Xml with correct chars/file encoded in "Windows-1252" (or at least closest to EXAMPLE B)?

Comment: Try calling `setOutput(dstOS, "windows-1252")` instead of `setOutput(dstOSW)`. The javadoc of the overload you are calling is warning you: *"**WARNING** no information about encoding is available!"*, which is why it sticks to ASCII and encodes anything else.

Comment: @Andreas I've called the setOuput as you suggested but unfortunately I've got the same xml result with "escaped" chars. (That was how I had it initially).